# Feasible trip itineraries using only Pasporta Servo?

Tags: pasporta-servo

What regions of the world make a good target for backpacking-style travel using only Pasporta Servo and public transportation (no car-renting)? Europe seems to be the most densely populated with hosts according to the [Pasporta Servo Monda Mapo](https://pasportaservo.org/mapo/):

- 1000 for Central Europe
- 250 for South America
- 200 for North America
- 100 for China

What are some feasible trip itineraries?

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the US and routinely receive guests who arrive by public transport. Pick your area of interest, contact hosts, go there, and be flexible. It will be great.